# CSS Issues 100% Fluid height not working

Tags: html, css

Pls take a look at this code

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">
         <div id="header_inner">

         </div>
     </div>

     <div id="contentliquid">
         <div id="content">
             asdasdasdas   
         </div>
     </div>

     <div id="footer">
         <div id="footer_inner">
         </div>
     </div>

 </div>
```

CSS :

```
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#333;
}

p {
    padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    float: left;
    height: 237px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header_inner {
    float: left;
    height: 166px;
    width: 60%;
    top:30%;
    position:relative;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#contentliquid {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    background: #051f3b;
    height:304px;
}

#footer {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

#footer_inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    background: #c0db09;
    clear: both;
    float:right;
}
```

Middle section in blue should be 100% in height and footer should in the bottom.Currently middle section is not setting upto 100%,in short % in not working rather than px i-e 200px etc.but i want middle section to be 100%
http://jsfiddle.net/RyDAw/

Comment: Do you want it to have 100% height of the viewport or 100% height of the space between header and footer so that the footer is always sticky at the bottom? Can the content be longer than the viewport?

Comment: just want the space between header and footer to be 100% in every resolution

Comment: content section 100% height is not working,

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a 100% height on a floating element. Since the floating elements are "extracted" of DOM flow you can't define their size in %. Try to remove the `float: left` from `#content_liquid` and you should be able to use % for height.

Comment: The conten_liquid section now moves to header area

Comment: @user2451541 It needs a clear:both... sorry, i forgot to tell. see here http://jsfiddle.net/guybrushthreepwood/G5znF/

Comment: same result,100% not working.I just want be default 100% height

Comment: @user2451541 perhaps i've not understood something of your question. But i've made some other changes, would you like to check again?  http://jsfiddle.net/guybrushthreepwood/G5znF

Answer (score -2):

```
CSS

body, html{
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#333;


}

p {
    padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;

    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    float: left;
    height: 237px;
    width: 100%;

}

#header_inner {
    float: left;
    height: 166px;
    width: 60%;
    top:30%;
    position:relative;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#contentliquid {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    background: #051f3b;
    min-height:304px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}

#footer {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;

}

#footer_inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    background: #c0db09;
    clear: both;
    float:right;}
```